# (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run [the website code to create the image.](https://github.com/EvilPort2/Sign-Language/blob/master/create_gestures.py)

When I run the code it gives me an error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) 
/Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:274: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) 
in function 'contourArea'
```

I am not sure about the reason behind it.

Comment: Is your image in 32 bit format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The repo is clearly written for OpenCV 3.x. But, you are running on OpenCV 4.1. Repo code takes find_contour's second return value for contours( `find_contours(...)[1]` ). You should change 1 to 0.

Answer (score 3):

`cnts = cv2.findContours(...)[0]`

this should solve your problem as in OpenCV (4>) findContours(...)[0] gives you the contours